# Change MySQL query based on HTML drop down Node JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ajax, ejs

New to this whole thing and can't seem to find the answer to this problem. first, drop down menu rendered to an ejs template. I'm trying to get the second drop down to update based on the selections of the first. I was able to make an AJAX call and get the values to the second drop down. MySQL query that populates the second drop down is hard coded, I need to find a way for it to be dynamic. query results need to change based on HTML drop down option

app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mysql = require("mysql");
var path = require('path');


app.set("view engine","ejs");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
var con;

app.get("/",function(req,res){
con.query("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM gameinfo",function(err,result){
      if(err) throw err;
      res.render('home',{result:result});
  });
});
//**part it says "3pk" needs to be dynamic** 
app.get("/test",function(req,res){
  con.query("SELECT DISTINCT gamename FROM gameinfo WHERE category ='3PK'",function(err,result){
      if(err) throw err;
      res.send(result);

  });
});
```

home.ejs file

```
    <select name ="newCategoryD" id ="catSelection">
        <% for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){ %>
            <option>
                <%=result[i].category %>
            </option>
        <% } %>
    </select>
    <button id = "categoryBox">select this</button>

 <br></br>
 <div>
     <select id="games" ></select>
 </div>


 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#categoryBox').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
           type:'GET',
           url:'/test',
           dataType:'json',
          success: function(data){
              $('#games').empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                $('#games').append('<option>'+data[i].gamename+'</option>')
            }

          }        
});

 });
 });

 </script>
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Pass the value of the 1st dropdown in your ajax call, then in the code that returns the result, add a WHERE clause to limit the response to categories based on the passed value

Comment: i guess that's where i could use some help, how would you make that AJAX call? thanks again for the help

Answer (score 0):

Change your Javascript to:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#categoryBox').click(function(){
        var catID = $('#categoryBox').val();
        //   Note the url below. It adds catid=(#categoryBox value from above).
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'/test?catid=' + catID,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){
                $('#games').empty();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    $('#games').append('<option>'+data[i].gamename+'</option>')
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And your server code to this:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mysql = require("mysql");
var path = require('path');


app.set("view engine","ejs");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
var con;

var catid = req.query.catid;    // Get the catid value from the url.

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    con.query("SELECT DISTINCT category FROM gameinfo",function(err,result){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.render('home',{result:result});
    });
});
//**part it says "3pk" needs to be dynamic** 
app.get("/test",function(req,res){
    //  Query uses the value from the url.
    con.query("SELECT DISTINCT gamename FROM gameinfo WHERE category ='" + catID + "'",function(err,result){
        if(err) throw err;
        res.send(result);
    });
});
```